# A* algorithm in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, pathfinding

I wanted to know if my A* algorithm is well-implemented and if it could be optimized in any way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Vector2
{
    int x, y;
public:
    Vector2(int _x, int _y) : x(_x), y(_y) {}
    Vector2() = default;
    Vector2 operator +(const Vector2& other) {
        Vector2 temp;
        temp.x = this->x + other.x;
        temp.y = this->y + other.y;
        return temp;
    }
    int getX() const { return x; }
    int getY() const { return y; }

    friend class Map;
};

struct Node
{
    Vector2 position;
    int G, H, F;
    Node* parent = nullptr;

    Node() = default;
    Node(const Node& other) = default;
    Node(Vector2 pos):position(pos) {};

    void calc(const Vector2& endPos) {
        H = static_cast<int>((abs(static_cast<double>(position.getX() - endPos.getX())) + abs(static_cast<double>(position.getY() - endPos.getY()))));
        G = parent ? parent->G + 1 : 1;
        F = G + H;
    }

    bool operator==(const Node& other) const {
        return (position.getX() == other.position.getX() && position.getY() == other.position.getY()); 
    }
    bool operator!=(const Node& other) const {
        return !(*this == other);
    }
    bool operator<(const Node& other)  const {
        return(F < other.F);
    }
};

class Map
{
    std::vector<char> data;
    int size;
public:
    Map() = default;
    Map(int _size) : size(_size) {
        data.resize(size * size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size * size; ++i) data[i] = '.';
    }
    void display() const{
        for (int i = 1; i <= size * size; ++i) {
            std::cout << data[i - 1] << " ";
            if (!(i % size)) std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }
    bool getIfInDanger(Vector2 position) const {
        if (position.y < 0) position.y = 0;
        if (position.x < 0) position.x = 0;
        if (position.y >= 20) position.y = size - 1;
        if (position.x >= 20) position.x = size - 1;
        return(data[position.getX() + (position.getY() * size)] == 'X');
    }
    void setElement(char&& asda, Vector2 position) {
        data[position.getX() + (position.getY() * size)] = asda;
    }
};

class Solver
{
    Vector2 startPos, endPos;
    std::vector<Vector2> directions;
    Map map;
public:
    Solver(Vector2 _startPos, Vector2 _endPos, int size) : startPos(_startPos), endPos(_endPos){
        Map temp(size);
        map = temp;

        map.setElement('X', Vector2(14, 15));
        map.setElement('X',Vector2(15,15));
        map.setElement('X', Vector2(16, 15));
        map.setElement('X', Vector2(16, 14));
        map.setElement('X', Vector2(16, 13));

        directions.resize(8);
        directions[0] = Vector2(-1, 1);
        directions[1] = Vector2(-1, 0);
        directions[2] = Vector2(-1, -1);
        directions[3] = Vector2(0, 1);
        directions[4] = Vector2(0, -1);
        directions[5] = Vector2(1, 1);
        directions[6] = Vector2(1, 0);
        directions[7] = Vector2(1, -1);
    }
    bool aStar() {
        Node startNode(startPos);
        Node goalNode(Vector2(endPos.getX(), endPos.getY()));

        if (map.getIfInDanger(startNode.position) || map.getIfInDanger(goalNode.position)) {
            std::cout << "Either the start of this map is obstructed or so is the end.";
            return false;
        }

        std::list<Node> openList;
        std::list<Node> closedList;

        startNode.calc(endPos);
        openList.push_back(startNode);

        while (!openList.empty()) {
            auto current = Node(*std::min_element(openList.begin(), openList.end()));

            current.calc(endPos);

            closedList.push_back(current);
            openList.remove(current);
            if (current == goalNode) break;

            for (auto& direction : directions) {
                Node successor(direction + current.position);

                if (map.getIfInDanger(successor.position) || successor.position.getX() > 20 - 1 || 
                    successor.position.getY() > 20 - 1 || successor.position.getX() < 0 || 
                    successor.position.getY() < 0 ||
                    std::find(closedList.begin(), closedList.end(), successor) != closedList.end()) {
                    continue;
                }

                successor.calc(endPos);

                auto inOpen = std::find(openList.begin(), openList.end(), successor);
                if (inOpen == openList.end()) {
                    successor.parent = &closedList.back();
                    successor.calc(endPos);

                    openList.push_back(successor);
                }
                else
                    if (successor.G < inOpen->G) successor.parent = &closedList.back();
            }
        }

        if (!openList.size()) {
            std::cout << "No path has been found\n";
            return false;
        }

        auto inClosed = std::find(closedList.begin(), closedList.end(), goalNode);
        if (inClosed != closedList.end()) {
            while (*inClosed != startNode) {
                map.setElement('Y',inClosed->position);
                *inClosed = *inClosed->parent;
            }
        }

        map.display();
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Solver solve(Vector2(0,0),Vector2(19,19), 20);
    solve.aStar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Avoid numbered names

> ```
> class Vector2
> ```

What about this makes it a `Vector2`?  It seems like it holds position data.  Why not just call it `Position`?  Alternately consider `Vector2D`, `CartesianVector`, or defining your own namespace, e.g. `nonstandard::Vector` to differentiate it (please find a better name than `nonstandard` though).  Names should be descriptive if possible.  The `2` doesn't tell me why you aren't just using a `std::vector` there.

### Don't repeat yourself

> ```
>         data.resize(size * size);
>         for (int i = 0; i < size * size; ++i) data[i] = '.';
> ```

You calculate `size * size` on every iteration of the `for` loop and once previous.  Why not just calculate it once?  Even if the original would get optimized out by the compiler, this makes it clearer that the `resize` and the `for` loop are operating on the same value.

```
        std::size_t area = size * size;
        data.resize(area);
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < area; ++i) {
            data[i] = '.';
        }
```

I also changed to `size_t` as being a better type for indexing an array.  Note that this would make no functional difference in this case.  It is a good habit though.

I changed from the statement form of the `for` loop to the block form.  This can also be a good habit, both for readability and to avoid a bug where someone tries to put two statements into a `for` loop without the block notation.

> ```
>         for (int i = 1; i <= size * size; ++i) {
> ```

Similar problem with a similar solution.

```
        for (std::size_t i = 1, area = size * size; i <= area; ++i) {
```

Another alternative is

```
        std::size_t i = 0;
        std::size_t area = size * size;
        while (i < area) {
            std::cout << data[i];
            ++i;
            std::cout << ((0 == i % size) ? "\n" : " ");
        }
```

This saves an unnecessary subtraction but may be less readable.

Note that it also saves adding an unnecessary space at the end of each line.  I find that neater, but it's not a big deal either way.

A third version would be

```
        for (std::size_t i = 0, area = size * size; i < area; ++i) {
            for (std::size_t endOfRow = i + size - 1; i < endOfRow; ++i) {
                 std::cout << data[i] << " ";
            }

            std::cout << data[i] << "\n";
        }
```

This saves calculating the modulus on each iteration.  Instead it calculates a sum of three values every `size` iterations.  I'll leave it up to you whether this is more or less readable than the previous versions.  It should be more efficient but not necessarily enough to matter.

### Avoid magic values

> ```
>         if (position.y < 0) position.y = 0;
>         if (position.x < 0) position.x = 0;
>         if (position.y >= 20) position.y = size - 1;
>         if (position.x >= 20) position.x = size - 1;
>         return(data[position.getX() + (position.getY() * size)] == 'X');
> ```

Why `20`?  Looking through the code, it's because you set `size` to `20`.  So why not say that?

```
        if (position.y < 0) {
            position.y = 0;
        }
        if (position.x < 0) {
            position.x = 0;
        }
        if (position.y >= size) {
            position.y = size - 1;
        }
        if (position.x >= size) {
            position.x = size - 1;
        }

        return data[getIndexFrom(position)] == 'X';
```

And now we need a `getIndexFrom`

```
    std::size_t getIndexFrom(Position p) const {
        return p.getX() + p.getY() * size;
    }
```

This not only reads easier to me, it avoids accidentally doing the conversion differently somewhere.

### Consider a Priority Queue

> ```
>         std::list<Node> openList;
> ```

Rather than store this in a `std::list` and use the \$O(n)\$ `std::min` every iteration, consider a `std::priority_queue`.

```
        std::priority_queue<Node> unexploredNodes;
```

Note that you may need to put the indexes in the queue rather than the `Node` values themselves to get a performance improvement.

```
        std::priority_queue<size_t, std::vector<size_t>, CompareNodes> unexploredNodes;
```

You'd have to benchmark all three versions to see which gives the best performance.

You also may want to consider writing your own priority queue implementation.

I also changed the name from `openList` to `unexploredNodes` as being more descriptive.

### Save visited nodes in an array rather than a list

You store each visited node in `closedList` and use `std::find` to check if it's there.  Instead, consider using a boolean array:

```
        bool *explored = new bool[size * size];
        for (auto& e : explored) {
            e = false;
        }
        explored[map.getIndexFrom(current.position)] = true;
            || explored[map.getIndexFrom(successor.position)]) {
        delete(explored);
```

This turns an \$O(n)\$ `std::find` into a constant time array access.

### Bug

> ```
>         if (!openList.size()) {
>             std::cout << "No path has been found\n";
>             return false;
>         }
> ```

I'd prefer

```
        if (openList.empty()) {
```

as more readable, but that's not the bug.

What if the last open path is the correct one?  Then `openList` will have a size of zero and it will say that no path has been found.  You can fix this by changing

> ```
>             openList.remove(current);
>             if (current == goalNode) break;
> ```

to

```
            if (current == goalNode) {
                goalReached == true;
                break;
            }
            openList.remove(current);
```

Now the `openList` is no longer empty.

Or you can test on `goalReached` instead of the state of the list.  This is less reliant on the mechanics of the search.

### Consider using function returns to replace loop control

Rather than using a tracking variable or relying on the structure of the search, consider using another function to do the actual search.  Then you can replace the loop with

```
            if (findPath(goal, unexploredNodes, explored)) {
                if (explored[map.getIndexFrom(goalNode)]) {
                    auto parent = &goalNode
                    while (*parent != startNode) {
                        map.setElement('Y', parent->position);
                        parent = parent->parent;
                    }
                }

                map.display();
                return true;
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "No path has been found\n";
                return false
            }
```

Note that I changed the incorrect `inClosed` to `parent`.  This makes more sense for everything but the first element in the original algorithm.

And you have to create a function `findPath`

```
        template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
        bool findPath(const Position& goal, std::priority_queue<T, U, V>& unexploredNodes, bool *explored) {
            while (!unexploredNodes.empty()) {
                auto current = unexploredNodes.pop();
                current.calc(goal);
                explored[map.getIndexFrom(current.position)] = true;

                if (current == goal) {
                    return true;
                }

                for (auto& direction : directions) {
                    Node successor(direction + current.position);

                    if (map.getIfInDanger(successor.position)) 
                        || map.inBounds(successor.position)
                        || explored[map.getIndexFrom(successor.position)]
                       ) {
                        continue;
                    }

                    auto unexplored = std::find(unexploredNodes.begin(), unexploredNodes.end(), successor);
                    if (unexploredNodes.end() == unexplored) {
                        successor.parent = &current;
                        successor.calc(goal);

                        unexploredNodes.push(successor);
                    }
                    else {
                        successor.calc(goal);

                        if (successor.G < unexplored->G) {
                            successor.parent = &current;
                        }
                    }
                }

                return false;
            }
```

And then you need an `inBounds` function

```
    bool inBounds(Position p) {
        return p.getX() >=0 && p.getY() >= 0 && p.getX() < size && p.getY() < size;
    }
```

I find this version to read more naturally.

Comment: Using the term `Vector` is customary for coordinate tuples (or triplets). Vector is a direction which has the same components as a position. It's just a matter of interpretation. Moving the calculation of `size*size` out of the loop body will not affect the generated binary code. The compiler will deduce that `size*size` is loop-invariant and do that optimization for you.

Comment: Thanks for answering!. Well, I got a problem, and it's that since goalNode's parent has never been set to anything I get access violation reading location in parent->parent->position

Comment: Oh, and also in auto current = unexploredNodes.pop(); auto cannot be deduced since unexploredNodes.pop() returns void

Answer (score 2):

@mdfst13 has already done a good job reviewing your code, but there are still a few things left that you could change. It's mostly nitpicking, but there's no harm in being a bit pedantic in a code review:

- When you use a standard library function, don't forget to fully qualify it with `std::`. That way, it makes it clear what you're doing and it also makes it easier to look for standard library features in your code:

  ```
  H = static_cast<int>((std::abs(static_cast<double>(position.getX() - endPos.getX())) + std::abs(static_cast<double>(position.getY() - endPos.getY()))));
                        ^^^^^                                                            ^^^^^
  ```
- There's a reason I picked the line above: it seems that you're doing some `static_cast`s in order to provide the good types to `std::abs`, the ones that match its signature the best. That said, all these conversions would have been done implicitly and I doubt that your `static_cast`s make the code more readable. Even better: the header `<cstdlib>` has integer overloads for `std::abs` (while `<cmath>` contains the floating point overloads); you can simply include `<cstdlib>` and drop the `static_cast`s altogether:

  ```
  H = std::abs(position.getX() - endPos.getX()) + std::abs(position.getY() - endPos.getY());
  ```
- When you can, try to define your comparison and relational operators (and the other ones too by the way, apart from a few ones) as free functions outside of the class. Most of the time they are implemented in function of accessible class properties anyway, so it should be easy.
- In C++, it's not idiomatic for classes to have a `display` or `print` method. The idiomatic way to display a class is to overload `operator<<` between your class and `std::ostream&` so that it can be used with every compliant stream:

  ```
  std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Map& map) {
      for (int i = 0; i < map.size * map.size; ++i) {
          stream << map.data[i] << ' ';
          if (!(i % map.size)) {
              stream << '\n';
          }
      }
      return stream;
  }
  ```

  Note that you will probably need to make this overloaded `operator<<` a `friend` of `Map` or provide an equivalent of a `Map::getSize` method in order for this function to work.
- You could use some more standard library features to avoid some conditions. For example consider these lines:

  ```
  if (position.y < 0) position.y = 0;
  if (position.x < 0) position.x = 0;
  ```

  You can use `std::max` instead:

  ```
  position.y = std::max(0, position.y);
  position.x = std::max(0, position.x);
  ```

  While it doesn't change many things, it lessens the number of visible conditionals and can thus reduce the cognitive burden when you read the algorithm.

Comment: Its not uncommon for classes to have display/print method. **BUT** they normally *also* have an `operator<<` overload (which simply calls the display/print method if they exist).

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll take all the points into account